# Some users are automatically timed out while working. Peoplesoft 8.47

Tags: peoplesoft

Some users alone getting timeout issues. 
I am using Peoplesoft 8.47 and some users are automatically timed out. when they login again they are able to work normally. 
After 2 hours of time they are automatically timed out even while working.

Answer (score 0):

Please check app log on this folder:

{PSHOME}\appserv{DOMAIN NAME}\LOGS

View these two files, and check if there is anything abnormal.

TUXLOG.xxxxxx

APPSRV_xxxx.LOG